# motog 3rd gen, since update , tells me ui has stop working

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow

ever since I updated to marshmallow, I was getting SIM CARD ERROR, now I get
the UI has stop working to you want to wait?

Comment: Try clearing cache. If it doesn't help, do a factory reset.

Comment: What's your question?